# Stimulsoft : how to add one day to a datetime var

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimulsoft for my report. 
I have a variable in datetime type like "11/12/2013". I want to plus 1 day to this var, the goal must be "11/13/2013". 
There is any way to do that ? or I have to do that in code behind before send to report.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that inside the report definition.

Example for system variable 'Today' (returns datetime object):

```
{Today.AddDays(1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

use DateTime method AddDays(1)